# Notebook in VSCode displays no output for some stored variables

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Consider the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

csv = """Country,Total Cases,New Cases,Total Deaths,New Deaths,Recovered,Serious
China,74187,1751,2006,138,14796,12017
Diamond Princess,621,79,,,17,20
Singapore,81,,,,29,4
Japan,80,6,1,,20,4
Hong Kong,63,1,2,1,5,6
S. Korea,51,20,,,16,
Thailand,35,,,,17,2
USA,29,,,,3,
Taiwan,23,1,1,,2,
Malaysia,22,,,,15,
Vietnam,16,,,,14,
Germany,16,,,,9,
Australia,15,,,,10,
France,12,,1,,7,
Macao,10,,,,5,
U.A.E.,9,,,,3,1
U.K.,9,,,,8,
Canada,8,,,,1,
Philippines,3,,1,,2,
Italy,3,,,,,2
India,3,,,,3,
Russia,2,,,,2,
Spain,2,,,,2,
Nepal,1,,,,1,
Belgium,1,,,,1,
Sri Lanka,1,,,,1,
Finland,1,,,,1,
Egypt,1,,,,,
Cambodia,1,,,,1,
Sweden,1,,,,,"""

with open("data/covid.csv", "w") as file:
    file.write(csv)

df = pd.read_csv("data/covid.csv").fillna(0).astype(dtype = int, errors='ignore')\
    .sort_values(by='Total Cases', ascending=False)

latest = df.to_dict('list')

some_var = latest.keys()

print(latest.keys()) # It's a notebook. Printing or calling a variable does not matter.
latest.keys()
```

Please see the attached image to see the issue

[image: Display issue in VScode]

It works in a jupyter notebook on conda and if I run it via a normal python file. Which highlights that the issue lies with how VSCode displays notebook outputs

As you can see, VSCode does not display some outputs after running a cell, but does display others after running a cell.

If I try this in a conda environment, it works just fine:
[image: working in conda]

Any suggestions for why this issue only happens in VSCode & How I might go about fixing it? Is it a kernel thing?

Comment: It's a notebook. Printing displays exactly the same thing. I suspect the issue probably originates from the built-in Display method

Comment: As I've explained, it works in a normal notebook. I've also further explained that it appears to be an issue for my environment. The code I have given is essentially proof that it should work & that it's not an issue with the code. If you don't understand the question, please don't post

Comment: Question should ideally include enough info for us to **reproduce** the problem. Working version isn't of any help, as we still have no idea what you did incorrectly to reach not-working version. I did as your pre-edit post said, run the code in VSCode and it printed properly (without notebook). Which means the problem was not reproducible with the amount of information you'd given. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If I knew how to reproduce the issue I'd have probably fixed the issue myself. What I can do is provide a much simpler example. If you give me a second, I'll edit for more clarity. However getting upset with me for not providing 'reproducible code' on an issue that's clearly related to the IDE and its settings is unreasonable

Comment: Noone is getting upset. Downvote is one of the ways of telling you the question needs improvement. Start from the scratch. Try to once again observe this issue. When you do, describe all the steps you took up to this point. Otherwise best we can do is guess what could possibly go wrong.

Comment: I have simplified the code example significantly. I have reworded my questions and tried to be as concise as humanly possible. I can't really do any more to make this question any clearer. I still cannot offer steps on how to reproduce. I don't even have any speculations on where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by an extension within vscode called Leaflet Map.

It changed the default renderer for notebook cells in vscode.

If anyone else has issues with VSCode outputs in future, you can click the elipsis on the output cell -> Click Change Presentation & ensure you're using an up to date renderer:
[image]

Comment: Had to wait 2 days before I could do this